# REST API Deployment for Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, ionic-framework, deployment

Currently I'm learning to build a REST API (backend) with the ionic application (frontend), but I'm facing an issue in backend REST API deployment. Thus, I'm asking this question to get some clues and answers related to REST API deployment, since I'm really new and no clue how to deploy a REST API. I had checkout some tutorial on youtube, but it seem like most of the example in videos are not using the technologies or environment that same as the REST API I built. The following shown the technologies I used to built my system frontend and backend:

---

**REST API (BACKEND):**

1. Language: Java, Spring MVC Framework
2. Database: Hibernate,  Oracle SQL Developer
3. Web App Build Technology: Gradle, Gretty (To app start my application)

**Ionic Application (FRONTEND):**

1. Technologies: Angular Framework, HTML, CSS

**How the application is working in localhost?**

STEP 1: I will app start using Gretty plugin in gradle

STEP 2: I active the command "ng serve" (ionic serve) to run my ionic application

STEP 3: After both frontend and backend is successfully run, now I can access the provided link that generated from `ng serve` to access my web app and do anything I want.

---

Everything is working perfectly in local system, but it is different case when I test my ionic web app through my smartphone (Since ionic allows us to build progressive web app). The frontend ionic application will not able to communicate with backend when the operating environment of frontend is not in local system and I know it's really make sense, since my backend REST API haven't deploy which only able to operating on localhost. Therefore, I'm have tried to find solution on youtube and other internet sources to deploy my rest api online, but I don't see any information or deployment video that using the same technologies as I used to built my rest api (Spring MVC, oracle developer, gradle).

Thus, I'm asking this "stupid" question in here to find out whether any solution to deploy my rest api? or any suggestion to change the technologies that I used to built my rest api? or any mistakes I had made which violate the best coding practice in building rest api.

As a new programmer, I really appreciate the answers from all you guys. Thank you.

Comment: Simple answer. If your backend(has nothing to do with banking) is not public exposed, your smartphone has no chance to reach it.

There are many ways to deploy the backend. for the beginning and to learn the mechanics of distributed applications https://ngrok.com could do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's explain some concepts:

You backend is the application you coded, deployed on a server that exposes an endpoint for access - e.g. http://localhost:8080/yourApp -  where your host/domain is your current computer (localhost) and the port is 8080 or anything you setup.

If you want to access from you smartphone:

1) Since your app is hosted on your pc, you need to be connected to the same wifi network

2) From your host machine, where you deployed your app, look for your ip address.

- open your console/terminal
- type ipconfig/ifconfig
- look for your wifi and copy ipv4 address

3) redeploy your frontend pointing to **your host machine ip**

It worked before because you where on the same machine (localhost means redirect to your own device). When you switched to your phone it, also, redirects to your own smartphone.